# How to create Multidimensional array?

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

I want to create multidimensional array which has levels, groups and items.

Comment: Check it out this link....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176512/android-two-dimensional-arraylist-help

Comment: @Uttam,Thanks for post link, i am going to check

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not create an array of your custom defined objects?

```
class A{
    int t;
    int b;
}

List<A> test = new ArrayList<A>();
test.add(new A());
```

Comment: how to get values form this once passed to somewhere else?

Comment: Just as normal objects. test[0].t . Ob cource it is good practice to use encapsulation, add public int getT(), public int getB() and not access the fields directly.

Comment: How to set value

Comment: just as normal objects: test[0].t = 123 or preferably add a constructor to A

Answer (score 4):

To create Multidimensional array in static way,

Ex:

```
static final String listdesc[][][][] =
{
    { // grey
      {  // lightgray
        { "grey", "grey only" },
        { "lightgrey","#D3D3D3" },
        { "dimgrey","#696969" }
      },
      {  // darkgray
        { "grey", "darkgrey" },
        { "sgi grey 92","#EAEAEA" }
      }
    },
    { // blue
      {  // lightblue
        { "blue", "lightblue" },
        { "dodgerblue 2","#1C86EE" }
      },
      {  // darkblue
        { "blue", "darkblue" },
        { "steelblue 2","#5CACEE" },
        { "powderblue","#B0E0E6" }
      }
    },
    { // yellow
      {  // lightyellow
        { "yellow", "lightyellow" },
        { "yellow 1","#FFFF00" },
        { "gold 1","#FFD700" }
      },
      {  // darkyellow
        { "yellow", "darkyellow" },
        { "darkgoldenrod 1","#FFB90F" }
      }
    },
    { // red
      {  // lightred
        { "red", "lightred" },
        { "indianred 1","#FF6A6A" }
      },
      {  // darkred
        { "red", "darkred" },
        { "firebrick 1","#FF3030" },
        { "maroon","#800000" }
      },

    }
};
```

To create it programatically, refer to,

[Assign data to a four Dimensional Array at RunTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907307/assign-data-to-a-four-dimensional-array-at-runtime)